# Running a local web server for testing and development

Tags: django, wordpress, apache, nginx, webserver

I am working on a shared *nix sever where I do not have `root` privileges.

I am trying to build a site using `wordpress` and for development purposes I need to start a local web server (something similar to `django runserver`). However, I am not sure how to do that.

The server already has an instance of apache running however, I can't make any modifications to the config files as I don't have the required privileges.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use WAMP, MAMP, XAMP, or LAMP...depending on your platform/OS

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Please provide an explanation at least.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the server on a port that is >1024 and you won't need root credentials :)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. My question was which server I can install and run without root credentials. Or can I run multiple instances of apache without root privileges?

Comment: You can run any server without root privileges, just not on a port with a number <= 1024. so, if you run it on port 1025, it will work even when you are not root.